# Поставить напоминание на сайте

Tags: предложение, модерация, тревоги, новые-участники

В последнее время каждый ≈15-ый вопрос на сайте соответствует формату:

```
Помогите (решить задачу|с задачей):
Текст задания:
(какой-то текст)
Входные данные:
(какой-то текст)
Выходные данные:
(какой-то текст)
Заранее благодарен
```

Причем у авторов чаще всего 1-11 баллов репутации.
Можно ли тем, чьему аккаунту менее трёх дней, ставить такое напоминание:

---

#### Если вы решили задать вопрос – чудесно!

Но не спрашивайте:

- Как решить какую-то учебную задачу;
- Что означает текст ошибки;
- Почему не работает.

---

Если добавите, буду благодарен. Устал уже ставить флаги на подобных вопросах.

Comment: "каждый ≈15-ый вопрос на сайте соответствует формату" ...... если бы.... чаще ещё хуже, формат такой: "Помогите (решить задачу|с задачей)... Текст задания...Заранее благодарен"

Comment: есть ещё лучше - начинаются со слова "срочно". Может сразу создать шаблон на сайте для таких вопросов? Что бы они сразу отмечались флажком?:) но... Я когда то предлагал отвечать на такие вопросы, но максимально сложно. То есть, задача посчитать сумму чисел? ок, но в ответе будет шаблон как минимум плюс функции с stl, которые без справочника никто не знает как использовать. Но, думаю, это грубо, хотя, как минимум, люди бы любили такие вопросы.

Comment: Если не примерять все вопросы к своему уровню, то можно было бы их не трогать, а оставлять, как источник репы для начинающих. Вспоминаю свои студенческие годы, с удовольствием писал маленькие лабы (текст программ) для половины девушек с нашего потока

Comment: Да, поэтому, я (и много думаю других) игнорируем такие вопросы, оставляя для начинающих, которые смогут. Но есть много людей, которые считают своим долгом "закрыть такой вопрос". Да, я сам тоже закрывал подобные, но есть все таки два отдельных случая- когда человек хочет разобраться (это нужно помогать) и когда он пишет "срочно" (а вот тут точно нужно закрывать).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если честно, лично я, не имею ничего против таких вопросов, если к ним приложены "старания". Если видно что 90% алгоритма проделаны, или даны отрывки из доков (или любых других авторитеных источников), где есть теория решения проблемы, но автор не понимает как применить в конкретно его случае, то я очень даже рад помогать таким людям.

То что у кого-то 1 или "мало" репутации для меня не играет никакой роли. Я сам сюда пришёл после 3-х лет опыта работы. И у меня иногда бывают ступоры в простых случаях, так что репутация явно не показатель опытности автора. Лично для меня репутация - это просто показатель того, кто сколько пользы принёс сообществу SO, будь то в виде ответов или вопросов.

Когда автору надо просто получить ответ и не хочется разбираться что и к чему, тогда я оставляю комментарий, чтобы они приложили к вопросу свои "старания". И это, если честно сразу видно по вопросу, кому что надо. Не надо спрашивать как я их различаю, это просто приходит с опытом :)

Ну и всегда можно отредактировать вопрос так, чтобы в заголовке не было "Помогите решить задачу" или т.п., а поменять на тему, затрагивающую вопрос.